# Bootstrap - how to add row number automatically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, indexing, numbers, row

how to add row number automatically?
I donot want to use json data, does bootstrap have this ability to add rom numbers?

Comment: row numbers ... in what?

Comment: @zakiye M, please provide detail about your doubt. Cant understand which row you taking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, bootstrap itself does not do what you are asking.  If you are using another framework with it, the framework may provide you need you need.  (eg. angular uses $index for the loop index), or you can use some jquery to reference elements in your array.   Unless I am misunderstanding your question, bootstrap itself will not provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ordered element in bootstrap it will number will come automatically

```
<ol>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```